# evaluating limits with 2 variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the limit :

$\lim_{(x,y)\to  (2,2)}$ $\frac{x^2 + y^2 - 8}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} - \sqrt{8}}$

1. $−1$
2. $\infty$
3. $0$
4. $1$
5. none of the other choices
6. does not exist

How is the answer number 5, I thought it should be "does not exist"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$$x^2+y^2-8=$$
$$(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{8})(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-\sqrt{8})$$

You will find $$2\sqrt{8}.$$

Comment: Did you rewrite the numerator? What I did was rationalized the numerator.

Comment: @xyz You can simplify.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: If permissible, you may convert the expression to polar coordinates. We know that $x = r\cos\theta$, $y = r\sin\theta$, and hence $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$. So, $$\require{cancel}{x^2 + y^2 - 8 \over \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - \sqrt{8}} = {r^2 - 8\over r - \sqrt8} = {\cancel{(r-\sqrt{8})}(r + \sqrt{8})\over \cancel{r-\sqrt8}} = r+\sqrt{8}.$$